# Set cookie when county flag clicked

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set some cookies to my site when the language is changed, gut it doesn't work.

Here is the website: http://www.goodyearwines.com/

Here's the code i used:

```
function setCookies(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; ";

    if(expires){
        expires = setExpiration(expires);
        document.cookie += "expires=" + expires + "; ";
    }
    if(path){
        document.cookie += "path=" + path + "; ";
    }
    if(domain){
        document.cookie += "domain=" + domain + "; ";
    }
    if(secure){
        document.cookie += "secure; ";
    }
}


$( "a.qtrans_flag_en" ).click(function() {
    setCookies('thelanguage', 'eng', 3, '/', 'goodyearwines.com');
});

$( "a.qtrans_flag_zh" ).click(function() {
    setCookies('thelanguage', 'chi', 3, '/', 'goodyearwines.com');
});

$( "a.qtrans_flag_fr" ).click(function() {
    setCookies('thelanguage', 'fra', 3, '/', 'goodyearwines.com');
});
```

Any help is welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.cookie is not a simple variable, appending to it might not work. Instead try using this:

```
function setCookies(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){

    var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; ";

    if(expires){
        expires = setExpiration(expires);
        cookie += "expires=" + expires + "; ";
    }
    if(path){
        cookie += "path=" + path + "; ";
    }
    if(domain){
        cookie += "domain=" + domain + "; ";
    }
    if(secure){
        cookie += "secure; ";
    }

    document.cookie = cookie;
}
```

and define  function setExpiration()